# Iterate a SQL query via PYODBC and collect the results into a Pandas DF

Tags: python, sql, pandas, for-loop, pyodbc

I am trying to run a query over and over again for all dates in a date range and collect the results into a Pandas DF for each iteration.

I established a connection (PYODBC) and created a list of dates I would like to run through the SQL query to aggregate into a DF. I confirmed that the dates are a list.

```
link = pyodbc.connect(  Connection Details     )

date = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in pd.date_range('2020-10-01','2020-10-02')]
type(date)
```

I created an empty DF to collect the results for each iteration of the SQL query and checked the structure.

```
empty = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'Balance']) 
empty
```

I have the query set up as so:

```
sql = """
Select dt as "Date", sum(BAL)/1000 as "Balance"
From sales as bal
where bal.item IN (1,2,3,4)
AND bal.dt =  '{}'
group by "Date";

""".format(day)
```

I tried the following for loop in the hopes of aggregating the results of each query execution into the empty df, but I get a blank df.

```
for day in date:
    a = (pd.read_sql_query(sql, link))
    empty.append(a)
```

Any ideas if the issue is related to the SQL setup and/or for loop? A better more efficient way to tackle the issue?

Comment: Had you re-assigned with each loop `empty = empty.append(a)`, you would get a non-empty data frame. But **warning**: [Never call `DataFrame.append` or `pd.concat` inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the loop and run a **single** SQL query by adding `Date` as a `GROUP BY` column and pass start and end dates as parameters for filtering. And use the preferred parameterization method instead of string formatting which `pandas.read_sql` does support:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH ? PLACEHOLDERS
sql = """SALES dt AS "Date"
               , SUM(BAL)/1000 AS "Balance"
         FROM sales
         WHERE item IN (1,2,3,4)
           AND dt BETWEEN  ? AND ?
         GROUP BY dt;
      """

# BIND PARAMS TO QUERY RETURN IN SINGLE DATA FRAME
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=['2020-10-01', '2020-10-02'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't defined the day variable when you generated sql.
That may help:

```
def sql_gen(day):
    sql = """
    Select dt as "Date", sum(BAL)/1000 as "Balance"
    From sales as bal
    where bal.item IN (1,2,3,4)
    AND bal.dt =  '{}'
    group by "Date";

    """.format(day)
    return sql

for day in date:
    a = (pd.read_sql_query(sql_gen(day), link))
    empty.append(a)
```